# How to select a field with linq on datarow

Tags: c#, linq, datarow

I have this linq query :

```
string title = from DataRow r in (OleDB.DataItems.Tables[0]).Rows
select r.Title;
```

and I'd like to extract the field Title (from Database) on the row (rows will be 1, not more, so that's I put on a string and not in a string[].

How can I do it?

VStudio says that DataRow doesnt contain the definition of Title, but the field Title exist on the database.

I making confusion :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Frédéric Hamidi said, you don't need LINQ.

However, if you still want to do it that way (overkill) and you know that there is always a single table with a single row, do:

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();

var table = (from a in data.Tables.Cast<DataTable>() select a).Single();

var row = (from a in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() select a).Single();

String title = row.Field<String>("Title");
```

or

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();

var table = (from a in data.Tables.Cast<DataTable>() select a).SingleOrDefault();

var row = (from a in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() select a).SingleOrDefault();

String title = row.Field<String>("Title");
```

I used a `DataSet` because I don't know how your object is structured.

Comment: Why not select the field in Linq? `string title = (from r in OleDB.DataItems.Tables[0]).Rows select r.Field<string>("Title")).SingleOrDefault();`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need LINQ since you only want to fetch the `Title` field of the first row in the collection:

```
string title = OleDB.DataItems.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Title"];
```

Comment: That method doesnt exist (because, naturally, I haven't implemented it yet). In fact I think I can extract a field from a row...no?

Comment: @markzzz, in that case, you can use the indexer of the `DataRow`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
string title = (from DataRow r in (OleDB.DataItems.Tables[0]).Rows
    select r.Title).First();
```

Linq returns an enumerable collection as it doesn't know there will be only one item.  Calling the First method will return the first item from the query.

Edit: Hang on, I have blatantly missed the problem you originally mentioned (but you'll still need the above)!

A data row contains fields, not properties as such.  What you'll need to do is

```
select r.Field<string>("Title")
```

So your entire query will be

```
string title = (from DataRow r in (OleDB.DataItems.Tables[0]).Rows
    select r.Field<string>("Title")).First();
```

Comment: I prefer `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` if I know that there *must* be one and only one row. This way if something change and I forget to update that piece of code an exception is raised.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use FirstOrDefault, in case there are no rows:

```
string title = (from DataRow r in (OleDB.DataItems.Tables[0]).Rows
    select r.Title).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if you need to perform such an action, you would cast the DataRow object to your strongly typed object corresponding with the table in your database.

I assume there is a class "Book" which contains the field "Title":

```
Book selectedBook = (Book) from DataRow r in (OleDB.DataItems.Tables[0]).Rows[0]
string sTitle = selectedBook.Title;
```

Hope this helps.